# How to include cardslib to my Android project?

Tags: java, android, android-library, cardslib

I want to create a GridView like GooglePlay.

I found this [library](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) on Github. I don't exactly know how to include it to my project. I tried to add it in "Build Path", but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to export it as a jar file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to import library directory as a project in your Eclipse just like @ssantos said in the answer. However you have to do one extra thing to make it work.

All the code is in a sub folder called "java". You have to right click on it and make it as source folder.

For more information you can look at the official guidlines https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can find the library project here.-

https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/tree/master/library/src/main

I'd try importing that as a project in your workspace (and mark it as Android library), and then including it in your project Android libraries (`Project properties => Android => Library section`)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Android Studio, just add the following to your build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.3.0'
}
```